Trying to use javascript in my cefsharp browser
I'm trying to use bind my application with youtube video playing in cefsharp browser but it's not working. I don't get what is wrong with my code:
c#
private async void Music_Play_Pause_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //bring javascript method
        string script = "toggleVideoPlayback();";
        var response = await music_player.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);

        if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
        {
            bool isPlaying = Convert.ToBoolean(response.Result);
            MessageBox.Show($"Video playback toggled: {(isPlaying ? "Playing" : "Paused")}");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to toggle video playback.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error toggling video playback: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

javascript
function toggleVideoPlayback() {
    var videoElement = document.getElementById('player');
    if (videoElement) {
        if (videoElement.paused) {
            videoElement.play();
        } else {
            videoElement.pause(); 
        }
        return !videoElement.paused; 
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}


javascript and cs file is in the same folder and the message that I set to check, which is "Failed to toggle video playback." is the only thing that shows up. As you can see in my code, I expect when  button is clicked, I want video to be paused or played

You can use DevTools to debug javascript issues, make sure your script runs correctly from the devtools console. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

actually this is the first time I'm trying to use javascript in c# so I'm wondering if compiler automatically gets javascript without importing javascript in advance.
So what I mean is I have c# file and javascript in same folder and I'm wondering what I must do to let c# know which javascript file should I implement on my music_player(cefsharp)

I'm not sure what you are asking, please edit your question and provide more details. Please also have a read over https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage as it  covers many of the common topics.
